# Create Postgres RDS with rake db:create:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an app that I am migrating to Deis and want to use RDS for my Postgres instance.  I have Postgres set up but if i run `rake db:create:all` from my local machine, configured to point to RDS, I get:

`This task only modifies local databases. <db_name> is on a remote host.`

Is there a way to create the DB from an existing migration or the schema.rb file?

**Update 1**
Here is the `database.yml` file.  All environments inherit the default

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: <db user I created>
password: <PW>
host: <my_unique_host>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
port: 5432
```

**Update 2**
For the comment about just creating the DB then running `db:migrate` like normal, this is exactly the behavior I am not seeing.  If I have the DB active and run `rake db:migrate`, the process completes and I am presented a new terminal line.  No tables/columns are created.

Am I better off trying to do a local DB dump and restoring it into RDS?

**Update 3: Solution**
I have resolved this and wanted to share my learnings:

1. It appears that running the `rake db:migrate` command from a remote host was not working.  This may be possible but I was not able to figure it out.
2. What solved it was actually SSH'ing into the app container in the Deis cluster and running `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`.  This ack'd back saying the table was created and I was able to verify in the psql prompt.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you post your database.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3: Solution** I have resolved this and wanted to share my learnings:

1. It appears that running the rake db:migrate command from a remote host was not working. This may be possible but I was not able to figure it out.
2. What solved it was actually SSH'ing into the app container in the Deis cluster and running rake db:create and rake db:migrate. This ack'd back saying the table was created and I was able to verify in the psql prompt.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do manually the part done by rake db:create:all[[1]](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4569-rake-dbdrop-dbcreate-dont-work), so connect to the DBMS and create the db by running command

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

migration can be done in normal way via `rake db:migrate`

Comment: See my second update above. This does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks::LOCAL_HOSTS << "192.168.1.1" # Replace with the IP you want to connect from
```

P.S. Keep in mind, it is a dirty hack which may stop working anytime, since it alters a constant.